# Read Expand and Collapse in Excel

Tags: java, excel, import

I have a excel with the Expand and collapse option with + and -. 
Is there a way to read that value while reading the excel file in java? Can i know whether there is a expand or collapse present for that particular row when am reading it in my Java code? Like in the below image can i get to know that row 7, 9, 13, 21 have the collapse option?

[image]

Comment: Which implementation/framework you are using? I have tried it with Apache POI project, and it works fine for me. [Reference link could be checked Here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/apache-poi-excel-row-group-collapse.html)

Comment: In your sample you are setting the row collapsed. I want to check whether the row is collapsed?